# "Как рукой сняло" — ударение

Tags: фразеология, орфоэпия

Вообще, правильная форма *сн**я**ло.* А говорят реально *как рукой снял**о**.*

Так как же быть: следовать норме или говорить как все?

Comment: Загляни в БТС...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заглянула в БТС (как посоветовали):
[снять](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)... **Как рукой сняло́** *что*. Внезапно прошло, бесследно исчезло (о боли, усталости и т. п.).

Посмотрела в словаре трудностей русского языка (Н. Еськова):
[снять](https://books.google.ee/books?id=vFimCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA384&lpg=PA384&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=wmQpBowhU3&sig=ACfU3U3i4QaX04BPTJksY4DkqlZeK5LbtQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEwq-F_KP9AhWVr4sKHUj5AKc4ChDoAXoECBcQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false)... как рукой сня́ло *и* сняло́ (*бесследно прошло*);
**!** *не рек.* сняло́; *не рек.* сня́та; *неправ.* сня́ла; *неправ.* снято́, сняты́.

Поглядела на "Грамоте" ([вопрос № 264220](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE&start=16725)):
В телевизионной рекламе говорили: "Боль как рукой снялО. "Открыл словарь ударений и нашел там единственный вариант — "снЯло". Выходит, что в рекламе говорили не правильно?
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Да, это ошибка. Нормативно: снЯло (но снялА).

Обнаружила окончательную, можно сказать, "разрешительную" запись в "Грамматике русского языка" ([§ 1615](https://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5315&0a0=1761)):

> Примечание 2. Наряду с ударением на флексии в форме прош. вр. жен. р. глаголы, перечисленные в п. 1–3, и их префиксальные образования в разг. речи иногда получают ненормативное ударение на флексии в форме прош. вр. сред. р. Это находит отражение и в поэзии. Отмечены следующие случаи просторечного ударения: <...> *сняло́* (при литературном *сня́ло*, но только: *как рукой сняло́*, разг., совсем прошло, о боли, болезни)...

Я всегда говорила *как рукой сняло́*. И рада, что счет 3:1 в пользу привычного (пусть — просторечного!) варианта позволяет мне и дальше так говорить.

Comment: Отлично, Римма, спасибо большое!)

Comment: И тебе, Артём, поклон. Рада, что наши мнения и привычки совпадают. И удивляюсь — как это я пропустила этот вопрос?

Comment: Вот уж не знаю))

Comment: Доброе утро, Рим! Вчера услышал рекламу со словами "происходит выставка", а сегодня утром увидел сообщение в лыжном чате о том, что произошли лыжные гоночки. То есть, конечно, должно быть "проходит" вместо этого. А ты (или кто-то ещё, если прочитает) с таким сталкивалась?

Comment: Мне по душе "проходит выставка", "проходила выставка". Но "происходит — происходила" тоже встречается. (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&ei=0jn3Y-mZCseprgTypYC4Cw&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjpypzwsav9AhXHlIsKHfISALc4HhDy0wN6BAgDEAQ&biw=1366&bih=657&dpr=1) У Э. Лимонова есть интересное предложение: *Встречает  на  огромном, залитом  солнцем  гольфовом поле, на берегу океана, где происходит  выставка
красоты автомобилей.*

Comment: Интересно, Римма, спасибо за пример и вообще!)